# Cannot Debug Files Named index.ts On Nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nodemon

I am encountering a very strange issue with nodemon. Breakpoints do not work on any file that has the name `index.ts`, despite the fact that nodemon reloads the server any time a change occues in them. Here is my setup:

**Dockerfile.dev**:

```
FROM node:lts-fermium
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9229
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

**Part of docker-compose-dev.yaml:**

```yaml
crossover-api:
    container_name: crossover-api
    build:
      context: ./crossover-server-new
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./crossover-server-new/:/app
    depends_on:
      - crossover-mysql
      - crossover-keycloak
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '9229:9229'
```

**nodemon.json:**

```json
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        "node_modules/**/node_modules"
    ],
    "watch": [
        "index.ts",
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "ext": "ts",
    "exec": "yarn lint && yarn build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ."
}
```

**Nodemon debug log:**

```
$ nodemon --dump
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] reading config ./nodemon.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 30 to restart
[nodemon] ignoring: ./.git/**/* node_modules/**/node_modules
[nodemon] watching path(s): index.ts src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
--------------
node: v14.18.1
nodemon: 2.0.15
command: /usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon --dump
p
OS: linux x64
--------------
{
  run: false,
  system: { cwd: '/app' },
  required: false,
  dirs: [ '/app/src' ],
  timeout: 1000,
  options: {
    dump: true,
    verbose: true,
    ignore: [
      '**/.git/**',
      '**/.nyc_output/**',
      '**/.sass-cache/**',
      '**/bower_components/**',
      '**/coverage/**',
      '**/node_modules/**',
      '.git',
      'node_modules/**/node_modules',
      re: /.*.*\/\.git\/.*.*|.*.*\/\.nyc_output\/.*.*|.*.*\/\.sass\-cache\/.*.*|.*.*\/bower_components\/.*.*|.*.*\/coverage\/.*.*|.*.*\/node_modules\/.*.*|\.git|node_modules\/.*.*\/node_modules/
    ],
    watch: [ 'index.ts', 'src/**/*', re: /index\.ts|src\/.*.*\/.*/ ],
    exec: 'yarn lint && yarn build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 .',
    monitor: [
      'index.ts',
      'src/**/*',
      '!**/.git/**',
      '!**/.nyc_output/**',
      '!**/.sass-cache/**',
      '!**/bower_components/**',
      '!**/coverage/**',
      '!**/node_modules/**',
      '!/app/.git/**/*',
      '!node_modules/**/node_modules'
    ],
    ignoreRoot: [
      '**/.git/**',
      '**/.nyc_output/**',
      '**/.sass-cache/**',
      '**/bower_components/**',
      '**/coverage/**',
      '**/node_modules/**'
    ],
    restartable: 'rs',
    colours: true,
    execMap: { py: 'python', rb: 'ruby', ts: 'ts-node' },
    stdin: true,
    runOnChangeOnly: false,
    signal: 'SIGUSR2',
    stdout: true,
    watchOptions: {},
    execOptions: {
      script: null,
      exec: 'yarn lint && yarn build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 .',
      args: [],
      scriptPosition: null,
      nodeArgs: undefined,
      execArgs: [],
      ext: 'ts',
      env: {}
    }
  },
  load: [Function (anonymous)],
  reset: [Function: reset],
  lastStarted: 0,
  loaded: [ '/app/nodemon.json' ],
  watchInterval: null,
  signal: 'SIGUSR2',
  command: {
    raw: {
      executable: 'yarn lint && yarn build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 .',
      args: []
    },
    string: 'yarn lint && yarn build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 .'
  }
}
```

Comment: If you take Docker out of the picture, does this setup work with a plain Node development setup?